# Old store redirecting to new one when same database is used for new magento

Tags: database

I installed fresh magento 1.9.2.3 with same old database which i used for magento 1.9.2.2. Now when I open magento 1.9.2.2 it is redirecting to magento 1.9.2.3 home page. Is there anything i have to change inside the code?

Comment: Do you use different domains? Have you changed the URLs in the core_config_data table?

Comment: No. How to do that? Kindly help me as am a beginner in this. Also images are not displayed in magento 1.9.2.3

Comment: First have a look ate your app/etc/local.xml file to see which db is used for which store. Use phpmyadmin to look at your magento db, open the core_config_data table and search for like %base_url% eg:  'SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%base_url%' ' and set the value accordingly. Then clear you cache or delete the var/cache folder

Comment: Yea I changed the dbname in app/etc/local and I checked the core_config_data. It has the url of newly installed store.

Comment: why the images not showing in my new store? and there is no option to upload the image at backend/manage catalog/PRODUCT/images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for late reply may be this answer will be help others

Take a look @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/restore_base_url_settings

Open your core_config_data table in phpMyAdmin.

Find the following rows for your unsecure section, they should look like the following:

```
PATH                    VALUE
web/unsecure/base_url   http://www.example.com/
```

Replace http://www.example.com/ with your appropriate domain url (trailing slash necessary) and if you’ve installed in a subfolder append it with a / after it.

Comment: Yes you are correct. If we change the secure and unsecure url  in `core_config_data` with the respective domain url It will not redirect. But It is not adviceable to use the same database name for different installations. taking a backup and using it again is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

When We want to use the same database, We should not use the already used database name while connecting fresh magento with the database. Instead the databse should be exported via 'PhpMyAdmin' and while installing a fresh magento pack, this exported database can be imported using the 'import'option in 'PhpMyAdmin' after creating a new database with different name.

By using this method one can have as many magento needed with same database at backend. All we need to do is to take a backup by exporting it and importing it while installing a new one.